# Errett Bishop's formulation of Diaconescu's theorem

Tags: axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem) on Diaconescu's theorem states that

> Already in 1967, Errett Bishop posed the theorem as an exercise (Problem 2 on page 58 in *Foundations of constructive analysis*).

The exercise instructs the reader to

> Construct a surjection which is *not* onto.

*Definitions*

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and $f$ a function from $A$ to $B$.

1. If there exists an operation $g$ from $B$ to $A$ such that
   $$f\big(g(b)\big) = b$$
   for all $b$ in $B$, then $f$ is called *surjective* and said to be a *surjection*.
2. If $g$ is a function from $B$ to $A$, then $f$ is called *onto* and said to map $A$ *onto* $B$.

*Question*

Why is Bishop's exercise equivalent to Diaconescu's theorem?

Comment: It's possible to read the definitions like this: A function is "surjective" if it satisfies the hypothesis of the axiom of choice; it is "onto" if it fulfills the axiom of choice, i.e. there's a choice function acting as its right inverse. To find a surjection which is (italicized) *not* onto, you have to come up with a contraption that makes this function witness an omniscience principle if it were to be onto. This is what Diaconescu's theorem inherently achieves.

Comment: @SpectreDNZ Diaconescu's theorem says that the axiom of choice implies not merely some omniscience principle but the "ultimate" omniscience principle, the law of the excluded middle. So I would not regard Bishop's exercise as posing Diaconescu's theorem.

Comment: I suppose "an" omniscience principle allows flexibility to any kind of solution to that exercise. Notwithstanding, the law of the excluded middle is called "*the* principle of omniscience" by Bishop's terminology, and as it is this principle that pertains the most to set theoretical considerations among Bishop's omniscience principles, I see it as not far fetched to say that proving Diaconescu's theorem is the ultimate goal of this highly set theoretical problem posed among all the other analysis exercises given in that section.